# Programming a USB mouse connected to the Intel Edison Arduino expansion board

Tags: edison

How can I programme a USB mouse connected to the standard USB port of the Intel Edison's Arduino expansion board?  I would like to measure the displacement of the mouse and also specify the frequency of image capture using the mouse's optical sensor.  I do not know much about programming so tutorials relating to my project would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple introduction to using the USB mouse as an input device. That might be a good starting point.

http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2015/12/using-input-device-on-embedded-linux.html